# Draw coloured transparent polygons on top of texture in modern opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics

I am trying to render an image in the viewPort using `symmetry_create = 1`
and binding texture to it.

```
 static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
//vertexdata
        -symmetry_create,
        symmetry_create,
        0.0f,
        //uv
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        symmetry_create,
        symmetry_create,
        0.0f,
        //uv
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        symmetry_create,
        -symmetry_create,
        0.0f,
        //uv
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        -symmetry_create,
        -symmetry_create,
        0.0f,
        //uv
        0.0f, 0.0f};
```

My vertex shader looks like

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
    TexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

And fragment shader looks like

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 frag_color;

uniform sampler2D myTexture;
void main()
{
    frag_color = texture(myTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

I have setup my vao, vbo and indices correctly and thus I am getting the result as expected (ie: A provided image on the display screen).

Now I would like to draw 'n' number of transparent polygons on the image generated.For each polygon, I have thought of achieving using mouse cursor positions and clicks and render using `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, n);`.

If I use the same vertex and fragment shaders my result now is black opaque polygons on top of the image.
How to achieve transparency and color in the polygons. Do I need to another set of shaders(vertex and frag)?

Comment: Presumably you've read up on [how to configure and use blending states in OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)? How have you tried configuring your blending state so far?

Comment: Yes I have read after you ave shared the link, tried it using 
    // Enable blending
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);

but I dont get any result

Comment: I am using a different vertex and fragment shader for drawing the polygon on top of the texture right now..Is this the correct approach?